# "Till now, I was travelling by bus. From now on, I will travel by car." Is it correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense, past-tense

I want to tell my friend that when going to office, I was travelling by bus till now but now I'll travel by car. Is the following sentence grammatical correct? If yes, is it natural? And should I use comma after *till now*?

> Till now, I was travelling by bus. From now on, I will travel by car.

I think sentence is not correct because normally I haven't seen usage of past continuous with *till now*. Another possibility is

> Till now, I have been travelling by bus. From now on, I will travel by car.

Are both of above correct? Thank you.

Comment: I find the second much more natural.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Ok. However, is there any grammatical mistake in first one?

Comment: It's usual to use the present perfect (I have been [verb]ing) when the activity has continued until now.

Comment: Nobody normally says *Until now, I was thinking [something I no longer think]* - we say *Until now, I **thought** the moon was made of green cheese, but you have persuaded me to change my mind*. I don't see why the continuous form is any more suitable with how I ***travelled*** than with what I ***thought***. So I'd go with *Till now, I **travelled** by bus*. Which definitely works better for further back in the past: *Until this year, I **walked** to work* (probably not *...I **had been walking*** or any other complex verb form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that they both can be said: it is up to the writer's preference...